# Unclear suggestion: "This dictionary could be written as dictionary litteral."

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm to write automated tests for an API. PyCharm highlights one line in my tests and suggests:

> `This dictionary could be written as dictionary litteral.`

Is there a better a "style" to do this to make this message disappear?

```py
def test_get_products_combination_2(self):
    """
    TC-586:GET Products - combination 2 valid
    """
    params = {} # <--- this line is highlighted with the message above
    params["start_at_document"] = "100"
    params["document_limit"] = "2"
    path = "/v1/users/%s/products" % self.user_id
    r = self.client.request(path, params)
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change `params` to dictionary literal it should fix the warning:

```
params = {
    "start_at_document": "100",
    "document_limit": "2"
}
```

Comment: do you think this is a better style to do this?

Comment: I personally find this style more readable. If you don't like the warning there's probably option in PyCharm to disable it.

Comment: @Raituha: Using a literal like this is less verbose and looks cleaner than your code. Also, the dictionary is created once, before run-time, when the function definition is compiled to byte code, which is more efficient than re-creating it every time you call the function, which is what your code does.

Comment: @PM2Ring actually you're only half-way right about the creation. However it is more efficient, yes.

Comment: @Raituha: To expand on Antti's comment, `dict` literals _are_ a little more efficient than doing step by step assignments, but unfortunately they aren't actually pre-built at compile time in standard Python (aka CPython). Sorry about that. However, in recent versions of CPython literal tuples, lists, sets, and frozensets _are_ pre-built at compile time. Also, literal lists are converted to tuples and literal sets are converted to frozensets (when it's safe to do so).

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm actually supports this refactoring right out of box. Just navigate on the warning line, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>; a popup menu appears; the first item says "Replace dictionary creation"; so press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to get

```
params = {"start_at_document": "100", "document_limit": "2"}
```